# Unpredictable states error when refactoring smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, error

Ethereum smart contract functions are limited to around 16 local variables. When they exceed that number, `stack is too deep` error is generated.

The solution is to refactor the large functions into smaller ones. For example:

```
Contract A{
   function B(p1,p2,p3...pn){
   }
}
```

Can be developed as:

```
Contract A{
   function B1(p1,p2){
   }
   function B2(p3,p4){
   }
   ...

}
```

Now assume that some functions are dependent on the results of others. In other words, the change in state caused by a function affects how another one acts.

This issue I am thinking of is unpredictable state discussed in this [paper](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments) which states:

> In general, when a user sends a transaction to the network in order to
>   invoke some contract, he cannot be sure that the transaction will be
>   run in the same state the contract was at the time of sending that
>   transaction.

How can we ensure that a user that wants to transact with function `B1` then wants to transact with function `B2` without someone else changing the state caused by transacting with `B1` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some of the variables are temporary and can be contained inside their functions, you may be able to call `B1()` from inside `B2()`, which gets around the stack depth limitation while still guaranteeing execution order.

If you have to split it into two calls, and it matters in which order they are called you may need to manage the dependency  yourself. For example, write a variable in `B1()` and check it in `B2()`, calling `revert` if it hasn't been written.

Comment: Can you clarify what A1() is?

Comment: Sorry, I meant B1 and B2, ie the 2 functions in the example. Edited.